# Music group that does electric guitar covers of classical music?

Tags: cover, guitar

I'm looking for a specific group that does electric guitar covers of classical music. The traits I know about this group:

- Album cover is a white guitar similar to the Les Paul
- They made a cover of Ode to the Joy, Rondo Alla Turca and Can Can music.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible that you are thinking of the game soundtrack of Bachsmith II http://www.deezer.com/us/album/11803966? Actually the Rondo Alla Turca is from the first part: http://www.deezer.com/us/album/8440555 Seems that the performers are `The Notetrackers`. Here is the cover of the game that I think matches your description:
[image]